# Aligning a table (vertically) with a subfigure

Tags: tables, spacing, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I want to show three pictures and a tabel with explanatory text:

```
    ---------   ---------
    |       |   |       |
    | Pic 1 |   | Pic 2 |
    |       |   |       |
    ---------   ---------

    ---------      TABLE
    |       |   |txt | txt| 
    | Pic 3 |   |txt | txt|
    |       |   |txt | txt|
    ---------
```

I'm using `\subfigure` for to place the pictures, but regardless of if I put the `\tabular` inside a subfigure, alone or in a `\minipage`, it vertically aligns itself with the midpoint at the bottom of Pic 3:

```
    ---------   ---------
    |       |   |       |
    | Pic 1 |   | Pic 2 |
    |       |   |       |
    ---------   ---------

    ---------  
    |       |
    | Pic 3 |      TABLE
    |       |   |txt | txt|
    ---------   |txt | txt|
                |txt | txt|
```

How can I sort this? I know subfigure is old, but if possible I'd rather not start over with a new package. I've tried `\subtable` but no change.

It doesn't have to be perfect, a quick fix would be great! I've tried putting a negative `\vspace` before, but doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try to use `\begin{tabular}[t]{cc}` for the table?

Comment: [t] put it even further down, but using [b] worked as i wanted it. Thanks so much, and thanks for the hints of forum etiquette, Papiro!

Comment: @Wilhelm Pictures have their reference point at the bottom, so `\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}` is what you're looking for.